# A variable with datatype as Double with value '0.0' not appearing in JSON response

Tags: java, json

The response to a REST web service has a field of type Double. If its value is '0.0' that field is not appearing in JSON response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `@JsonInclude(Include.ALWAYS)` as javadoc says

> property is to be always included, independent of value of the
>   property

Comment: Should the annotation be on the Class or the field?

Comment: It depends whether you need to apply that rule to one field, or to all fields in a class